# Visual Basic - Array

Tags: vba, visual-studio

Say I have a list of variables like so, ranging from x0 to x1:

```
x0 = 0.0
x1 = 1.0
x2 = 3
x3 = 9
x4 = 18
x5 = 20
x6 = 30
```

There is a function within a software package I'm writing the code for which selects a point on a given co-ordinate (the actual function doesnt really matter).

call view.selectCircle(x, y, z, "Set", "Point")

What I want to do is write a loop function which runs this function for all my values of x0-x1. I've tried this but have failed to get it to work...

```
For i = 1 To 6

call view.selectCircle("x" & i, 0.0, 0.5, "Set", "Point")

Next
```

Sorry if this is an extremely basic question as I'm pretty new to programming!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes you need an array. Do you know how to declare and fill one?

Comment: You are probably not using `VBA` but `VB.NET`. If so, remove the tag `VBA` and add tag `VB.NET` so you can get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't currently have an array, you have 7 separate variables. If you want an array you have two options:

```
x = Array(0.0, 1.0, 3, 9, 18, 20, 30)

For Each point In x
    Call view.selectCircle(point, 0.0, 0.5, "Set", "Point")
Next
```

---

```
Dim x(0 To 6) As Double

x(0) = 0.0
x(1) = 1.0
x(2) = 3
x(3) = 9
x(4) = 18
x(5) = 20
x(6) = 30

For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    call view.selectCircle(x(i), 0.0, 0.5, "Set", "Point")
Next
```

Note that the different types of loop aren't relevant to the type of array, I've just used two examples to give you an option - they are interchangeable as far as these solutions are concerned.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I have a lot to learn it seems !

Comment: @Crescend0 no problem - I'd advise having a [read of this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) for more information. Also don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved your problem (green tick on the left)

Comment: Note that if the OP is using VB.NET, using `.Length` is preferable to `LBound` and `UBound`.

Comment: @Comintern good point, didn't see the `visual-studio` tag there which could suggest it isn't VBA. I just came to the question from a VBA feed...

Comment: FWIW, it *should* work in .NET if the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace is imported.